# How can I make this such that all can have write access

Tags: apache

I have installed Apache Web server for the purpose of local repository .

I have this lines for my directory .

```
  # Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
    # to the admin user.
    <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
        require user admin
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i provide write access to all the users not only the admin in this case .

Thanks .

How can I make this such that all can have write access (Not just the admin user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [require `valid-user`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider) instead.

```
<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
    require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```